# I have a problem with a war generated, somes jpa native querys it does not work

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with a generated `WAR` file, some JPA native querys when I put the `WAR` on the production server. I have a log file and the error that was thrown on the production server.

In my JPA Repository I had this method:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM ExpedientsDashboard exp WHERE exp.Company_Id = :companyId AND exp.Deleted_At = :deletedAt AND (exp.Status like %:status% OR (exp.LastState like %:status% AND exp.IsReOpen = 1)) ORDER BY exp.Id ASC /*#pageable*/",
countQuery="SELECT count(*) FROM ExpedientsDashboard exp WHERE exp.Company_Id = :companyId AND exp.Deleted_At = :deletedAt AND (exp.Status like %:status% OR (exp.LastState like %:status% AND exp.IsReOpen = 1))",
nativeQuery = true)
Page<ExpedientDashboard> findAllByCompanyIdAndStatusAndDeletedAt(
  @Param("companyId") Integer companyId,
  @Param("deletedAt") Integer deletedAt, 
  @Param("status") String status, Pageable pageable
);
```

It is a native query...

In the Controller, I only call the method to get data.
Locally, this works fine. But in production, it fails.

The output that from the log file on the production server is:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Sintaxis incorrecta
>   cerca de '@P0'

If I run the `WAR` locally it works perfectly, connected with the bdd on production.

Comment: what's the error? also please format your code.

Comment: Is SQL-Server version at production host identical to your local's?

Comment: `like %:status%`  looks weird. Maybe you should add `%` to the `status` variable instead having it inside your query.

Comment: Nikolay Shevchenko It's the same.. the war has the same string conection